# EE Calendar Tag & Low Yearly Achives

Tags: ee2, url, low-yearly-archives

Im using Yearly archives to display articles by month:

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" start_month="1" status="not closed" sort="desc" show_future_entries="no" start_year="" end_year=""} 
  {months} 
    {if num_entries > 0} 
      {month} / {num_entries} 
    {/if} 
  {/months} 
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```

I also have the EE mini calendar tag in my template.

**I'm trying to get the calendar tag to display the current month regardless of the url created by yearly archive tag.**

For example, I want December to show in the calendar tag but if I click on month links created by Yearly archive such as January and the url becomes: `news/month/2012/1/` the calendar changes to January and doesnt say on December. 
Ive tried playing about with `dynamic="no"` to no avail.

The beginning of my calendar tag looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:calendar channel="events" switch="calendarToday|calendarCell" start_day="monday" leading_zeroes="yes" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="no" dynamic="no"} 

{date format="%F %Y"}
```

Any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated [in the GetSat thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_yearly_achives_and_ee_calendar_tag) as well, this isn't an issue that has anything to do with Low Yearly Archives per se. It's native behaviour for [the channel:calendar tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/calendar.html) to change the month displayed by what's present in the URI. Even if you *didn't* put a LYA tag there, you'd still be able to change it by just simply adding `/YYYY/MM` to the URI.

That said, you should probably look at [the `month=` and `year=` parameters](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/calendar.html#month-year) and hard-code them using `{current_time}`. Something like this:

```
{exp:channel:calendar
    channel="events"
    month="{current_time format='%m'}"
    year="{current_time format='%Y'}"
    ...
}
```

Untested, but I'm guessing that's your best bet.

Comment: Hi Low, I understood what you were saying over on your help forums that this was not an issue with LYA but I thought I should illustrate the situation. Thanks for the tip with using {current_time}. It seems to do the job.